# How to obtain the precision score of "positives" instead of "negatives" with the cross_val_predict() function?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I use cross validation on a binary dataset.

Right, now when I enter the following lines:

```
clf = cross_val_score(cl_mnb,transcriptsVectorized, y=Labels,cv=6,scoring = 'precision')
print(clf.round(2))
```

I do get precision scores, but only for the the negatives; I want to have the precision of the positive cases.

When I look up the available metrics with sklearn.metrics.SCORERS, I don't  I cant find that option, does it exist?

Answer (score 0):

I feel the notation you are using in the question may not be correct, so please assist me if the answer does not solve your problem.

First of all, let's take a look at the [confusion matrix reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix).

`Precision` or positive predictive value:

[image]

Scikit-learn respects this formula and interprets 1 (or true) as positives. The condition positive and predicted condition positive are used to obtain the precision.

By positive cases, do you refer to condition positive cases evaluation? You can use the `recall` metric in this case, which is also offered by sklearn...

[image]

The `recall` evaluates your model prediction of real positives. Some of the question that it tries to solve are:
Is the model predicting the anomalies? Is the model identifying the cats in the data?

Then, maybe you need the prediction of 0 or False values. Follow the matrix and understand it, is the best way to improve!